# Overriding position of CSS Keyframes not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I want to override a previous CSS @keyframe animation.
First, the word comes in from the right and stays in the middle.
As soon as you click on the button, the same word should be animated to move from it's current position to the top.

However, the word doesn't move at all or simply makes a quick jump to that position.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vpfd672g/10/

```
<button type="button" class="test-button">Click Me!</button>
<div id="window">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="word">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#window {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 221px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.word {
  position: relative;
  animation: slide-in-right 2s ease-out forwards;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes slide-in-right {
  0% {
    right: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out-top {
  100% {
    top: -100px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```
<script>
let word = document.querySelector(".word");
let tstB = document.querySelector(".test-button");

tstB.addEventListener('click', doStuff);

function doStuff() {
  word.style.opacity = 1;
  word.style.animation = "slide-out-top 2s forwards ease-out"
}
</script>
```

What is it that's causing the issue or what am I missing out?

Comment: 0% position should be mentioned in 'slide-out-top'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add below style to `slide-out-top`.

```
0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpfd672g/11/).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't thought that this was needed? Any explanation/source why it is?

Comment: Animation requires a starting point and an end point, to animate. You provided only what should happen at 100%, hence it was jumping.

Comment: Is the starting point not provided by the previous animation with "forwards"?